# When using a variable, that is called from a file, prints variable name itself. How to resolve this?

Tags: tcl, expect

I have following scenario:

```
2000::$var/22    
2000:400::$var/22
2000:800::$var/22
```

I want store the above 3 lines in text file. and call one by one to print 1 to 15 as shown below.

```
2000::1/22    
2000::2/22    
2000::3/22    
2000::4/22    
2000::5/22    
.
.
.
2000::15/22
```

When I import each line from a file, its not printing as shown above. Its prints variable name itself as shown below.

```
2000::$var/22    
2000::$var/22
```

Please guide me, How to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Balu P.

Comment: It helps to show us your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCL has a command called `subst` which will do what you want. All you have to do is to set the value for `var`, then call `subst`:

```
set fileHandle [open data.txt]

while {[gets $fileHandle line] != -1} {
    for {set var 1} {$var <= 15} {incr var} {
        puts [subst -nocommand $line]
    }
}
```

## Discussion

- The `while` loop will read the file, line by line, until the end of the file
- Within the while loop, I set the variable `var` to 1 .. 15
- Then I call `subst` to do substitution before printing it out

## Update

Per Glenn Jackman's excellent suggestion, I updated the code with `-nocommand` to prevent command expansion, which could open door for malicious code.

Comment: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/subst.htm -- for safety (in case you don't have complete control over that file) use the `-nocommands` option

Comment: @glennjackman does not help: `subst -nocommands {$::env([exit])}`

Comment: Hmm, looks like a Tcl bug. A less "destructive" example: `set foo bar;  array set a [list [pwd] "hey!"]; subst -nocom {this is $foo [pwd] here}; subst -nocom {this is $foo $a([pwd]) here}`